# Redux: yield inside an anonymous function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-saga

So, i am entirely new to `Reudx-Saga` and i have been testing it a for a few days.

I have a working understanding of generators, actions, redux-stores, sagas and others. Have some good experience with JS overall.

I have a scenario where i have a function as follows:

```
project().itemClicked(val => /* do something with */)
```

Now, i am trying to put this code inside a generator function, in my `saga`. I basically need to `put` an action, but for that, i need to use the `yield` keyword. I need to put the `val` returned by the callback using `yield put`.

I have to make a few other `yield call(function..)` calls after executing the above requirement. I tried wrapping my function inside a `Promise`, but the problem with that is, the promise is only getting called only once `intemClicked` is fired and thus the rest of my `yield` calls are being blocked.

Is there a way i can `yield` inside my anonymous function ?

Pardon my wording because i am still learning/understanding `Redux-Saga`.

Comment: you can't yield from an arrow function, use the function* () {...} syntax to define a (anonymous) generator (I'm not sure I get the whole question, but I think this is a useful bit for you)

Answer (score 0):

The solutions depends on if the callback can be called multiple times or only once.

If it is going to be called only once, you first approach - converting it to promise - was the right one, you just need to use `fork` to make the wait non-blocking.

```
function * itemClickedSaga() {
  const val = yield new Promise(resolve => {
    project().itemClicked(resolve)
  })
  yield put(someActionCreator(val))
}

function * someSaga() {
  // waits for the promise in different saga
  // using fork to not wait for the call bellow
  yield fork(itemClickedSaga) 
  yield call(somethingSomething)
}
```

In case the callback can be called multiple times, you might want to use an `eventChannel`:

```js
function createItemClickedChannel = () => {
  return eventChannel(emitter => {
    project().itemClicked(emitter)
  })
}

function itemClickedSaga(val) {
  yield put(someActionCreator(val))
}

function * someSaga() {
  const itemClickedChannel = yield call(createItemClickedChannel)
  yield takeEvery(itemClickedChannel, itemClickedSaga) 
  yield call(somethingSomething)
}
```